# How to support IE8 with google charts?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jsapi

I'm creating a Google Charts page similar to the following example: http://plnkr.co/edit/paoZQTo1vFSxNJxe45io?p=preview

My chart already works fine, except on Safari 5.0.3 with IE8 UserAgent Mode (which I have to support). Probably you can take any safari to test this.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Result of expression 'a.runtimeStyle' [undefined] is not an object
```

The page displays:

```
<div id="google-visualization-errors-all-1" style="padding-top: 2px; display: block; ">
    <div id="google-visualization-errors-0" style="font: normal normal normal 0.8em/normal arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 5px; ">
        <span style="background-color: rgb(192, 0, 0); color: white; padding-top: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-left: 2px; ">
            Result of expression 'a.runtimeStyle' [undefined] is not an object.
                <span style="font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 10px; color: black; text-align: right; vertical-align: top; ">×</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What might be the problem here, and how could I support IE8?

Comment: Google does not support IE8 for any of their products any more, so given the error message you're getting I think your chances of getting Google Charts working in IE8 are fairly low.